# Installed node/npm on macOS Sierra into /usr/local/bin, not executable

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, path, macos-sierra

Fresh install of macOS Sierra on a new MBP, `/usr/local/bin` requires root to access the files. But many programs, including `node` and `npm` install their executables to `/usr/local/bin`. I can't execute them unless I'm root. Am I supposed to change permissions on `/usr/local/bin` in macOS Sierra? Seems there's a reason for the stricter permissions.. Are tools like node/npm just not up to date with how things are done in the latest mac OS and I should move those files to somewhere else like `/usr/bin`?

Answer (score 1):

Change npm's default directory to another directory that requires you not to run it as root

```
mkdir ~/my/path
npm config set prefix '~/my/path'
```

Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

```
export PATH=~/my/path/bin:$PATH
```

Back on the command line, update your system variables:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Test: Download a package globally without using sudo.